# Usage of raw_input in python

Tags: python, database

I am having so much trouble with this python script:

```
import time
print "Loading Interface"
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Loaded Interface"
time.sleep(1)
question_one = raw_input = "Request: Enter your name: "
question_two = raw_input = "Request: Enter your password: "
time.sleep(1)
print "Searching for %s with the password %s in our database." % (question_one, question_two)
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `question_one = raw_input = "Request: Enter your name: "` should be `question_one = raw_input("Request: Enter your name: ")`.

Comment: *Please* explain the problem in your question. Do not answer in the comments. Edit your question and explain what your code does, what it should do that it doesn't and how it has to behave.

Comment: "_Problems with PYTHON"_ is not an acceptable title. Actually describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is a function, so you have to call it and not just assign some value to it.

Try this:

```
question_one = raw_input("Request: Enter your name: ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for one, its not clear what you're asking. also, you have the program delay on purpose when it's not really loading... not sure why you would want to do that. and you're not actually calling raw_input, you're just assigning a variable to it. instead, try this:

```
question_one=raw_input("Request: enter your name: ")
```

this ^^^ will actually ask the user a question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean that the problem is that the raw import prompt does not work. This is because raw_import is a function, and the (optional) argument can be the import prompt (see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

i.e. this should work:

```
import time
print "Loading Interface"
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Loaded Interface"
time.sleep(1)
question_one = raw_input ("Request: Enter your name: ")
question_two = raw_input ("Request: Enter your password: ")
time.sleep(1)
print "Searching for %s with the password %s in our database." % (question_one, question_two)
```